# Problems running a program tested in ubuntu (according to developers)

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

**Problem**

I'm trying to run a simple program following a simple installation procedure (plus I've used it in the past).

The files the program contain are these

```
libiomp5.so  MOPAC2016.exe
```

When executing it I get the following error:

```
bash: /opt/mopac/MOPAC2016.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

**System Info**

I am running Lubuntu 20.04

The program is for x86 architecture and uname -a in my PC returns

```
Linux eoan 5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 10:28:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Miscellaneous**

The website states the program was tested in ubuntu and redhat. It includes also this paragraph, that I believe should be useful somehow:

> For other flavors of Linux:  The version of glibc that the Linux OS
> uses must be identified.  If the attempt to install MOPAC works,
> great!  If it complains that glibc is missing, identify which version
> of glibc is used by the Linux operating system, then use the
> appropriate CentOS version.  These are: CentOS 5: glibc-2.5 CentOS 6:
> glibc-2.12, CentOS 7: glibc-2.17.

[From MOPAC website](http://openmopac.net/Download_MOPAC_Executable_Step2.html)

Comment: Have you done `sudo ldconfig`? RTFM first, this is just a guess.

Comment: @steeldriver same output

Comment: @waltinator there is no manual but only an installtions instructions. I get same thing using that

Comment: JIC, I've given execution permissions to the files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the zip file.  The MacOS executable for MOPAC2016.exe had been loaded instead of the Ubuntu version.

The Ubuntu version of MOPAC2016.exe has now been put into the zip file uploaded to openmopac.net, downloaded onto a Ubuntu machine, and verified. This occurred at 13:00GMT on 6/28/2020

My apologies for this error.  My thanks and compliments to the user who alerted me to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the software developers packed wrong files to wrong archive.

The main executable is [for](https://superuser.com/q/1050160/842966) Apple macOS:

> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget http://openmopac.net/MOPAC2016_for_Linux_64_bit.zip
> unzip MOPAC2016_for_Linux_64_bit.zip
> $ file ./MOPAC2016.exe 
> ./MOPAC2016.exe: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable
> ```

As a workaround you have to try CentOS 7 version of the software:

> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget http://openmopac.net/MOPAC2016_for_CentOS-7.zip
> unzip MOPAC2016_for_CentOS-7.zip
> ```

as it has correct file type:

> ```
> $ file MOPAC2016.exe 
> MOPAC2016.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped, too many notes (256)
> ```

So you have to download [MOPAC2016_for_CentOS-7.zip](http://openmopac.net/MOPAC2016_for_CentOS-7.zip) and then follow their instruction about putting it to `/opt/mopac` and so on.

Comment: solved. thanks man, i can't believe this happened.

Comment: Just accepted the solution from the creator of the program that fixed the issue too (I probably owe you an apologize, but think this is the right way).